# Linked List ProductOperation() from a simple java program

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, nodes

I am taking a course in Data Structures at University and I am having troubles understanding why my Linked list `ProductOperation()` has several bugs, especially at the `addProduct()`, `deleteProduct()` and `displayProduct()` methods.
Here is my node class:

```
public class Node {

    private Product info;
    private Node link;

    public Node(Product product) {
        this.info = product;
        link = null;
    }

    public Product getInfo() {
        return info;
    }

    public Node getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public void setProduct(Product product) {
        info = product;
    }

    public void setLink(Node newLink) {
        this.link = link;
    }
}
```

Here's my Product code:

```
public class Product {

    private String name;
    private int quantity;
    private double price;
    private double total;

    public Product(String name, int quantity, double price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return this.quantity;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return this.price;
    }

    public double getDouble() {
        return this.total;
    }
}
```

And here's my `ProductOperation()` code:

```
public class ProductOperation {

    private Node head;

    public ProductOperation() {
        head = new Node(null;
        }

    public void addProduct(Product product) {
        Node newNode = new Node(product);
        if (head == null) {
            head = newNode;
        } else {
            Node current = head;
            while (current.getLink() != null) {
                current = current.getLink();
            }
            current.setLink(newNode);
        }
    }

    public double calculateTotalPrice(Product product) {
        return product.getQuantity() * product.getPrice();
    }

    public void searchProduct(String target) {
        Node current = head;
        Product product = null;
        while (current.getLink() != null) {
            if (product.getName() == target) {
                System.out.println("The price of " + product.getName() + " = " + product.getPrice());
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Sorry, the product " + product.getName() + " does not exist.");
    }

    public void deleteProduct(String target) {
        Product product;
        Node newNode = new Node(product);
        if (head == null) {
            System.out.println("List is empty");
        } else if (head.getInfo() == target) {
            head = head.getLink();
        } else {
            Node before = null;
            Node current = head;
            while ((current.getInfo() != target) && (current != null)) {
                before = current;
                current = current.getLink();
            }
            if (current.getInfo() == target) {
                before.setLink(current.getLink());
            } else {
                System.out.println("The target does not exist");
            }
        }
    }

    public void displayAllProducts() {
        Node node = head;

        System.out.printf("%%10s %30s %20s %5s ", "Name", "Price", "Quantity", "Total");
        System.out.println("====================================================================================");
        System.out.format("%%10s %30.2f %20s %5.2f ", product.getName(), product.getPrice(), product.getQuantity(), product.getDouble());

    }
}
```

Sorry in advance if this is a basic question/problem. I have asked my professor and he sent me a YouTube link which really didn't help.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: What means *a lot of bugs* in your case? Please, give us more details.

Comment: We definitely need to know what the bugs are as @M.Dudek said. Also if there really are a lot, then we can't really go through and find them all for you, that's your job. Your question should be focused on one problem that you can't solve after a great deal of effort and research.

Comment: Hi, This could be a good place to learn, but definitely, you need to divide the problems, if there are lots o bugs pick one and try to solve it.  Explain why do you think your operations do not work.

Answer (score 0):

Right, a lot of bugs, here what I could find at first sight, I don't provide the fixes since it's more useful if you do it by yourself.

```
public void searchProduct(String target) {
    //You start with head, but never check if head is null
    Node current = head;
    //product is initialized to null and remains null, since there is no other assigment to it
    Product product = null;
    //With this condition you skip the last valid node of the list (that has link == null)
    while (current.getLink() != null) {
        //product here is null, get it first from the current node
        //Strings must be compared with equals(), not with ==
        if (product.getName() == target) {
            System.out.println("The price of " + product.getName() + " = " + product.getPrice());
        //Here you should return, since the search is successful
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Sorry, the product " + product.getName() + " does not exist.");
}
```

About deleteProduct:

```
public void deleteProduct(String target) {
    Product product;
    //Why a new Node? You are deleting
    Node newNode = new Node(product);
    if (head == null) {
        System.out.println("List is empty");
    //Again, must compare with equals(...), moreover you are comparing a Node with a String
    //First, get the product then compare product's name with target
    } else if (head.getInfo() == target) {
        head = head.getLink();
    } else {
        Node before = null;
        Node current = head;
        //Same error as above, getInfo() returns a node, target is a string
        while ((current.getInfo() != target) && (current != null)) {
            before = current;
            current = current.getLink();
        }
        //Same error, plus here current may be null and you may get a NPE
        if (current.getInfo() == target) {
            before.setLink(current.getLink());
        } else {
            System.out.println("The target does not exist");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Rocco, Can you give a comment for the AddProduct() method? Would thank you if you do so.

Comment: @NoelStanferson I didn't comment it since it looks ok, instad the constructor is wrong and should be removed.

Comment: You mean which constructor? If that's from the ProductOperation then cannot be removed, it must be part of the java file

Comment: @NoelStanferson the ProductOperation constructor has nothing to do since head is already null by default, so the constructor should be empty (or removed, that means the compiler will provide an empty default constructor). The initialization you do `head = new Node(null);` is not consistent with the other parts of the class.